# How to use conversion type functions in oracle without using <select .. from> clause

Tags: sql, oracle, select, type-conversion, to-date

I want to use <to_date> function on a string (which doesn't require any data from any table) in oracle without using <select .. from> clause

I want to show the string '01011912' into to the date 01/01/1912 as follows : to_date('01011912', 'DDMMYYYY'), but the it requires select and from keywords :(

Comment: That's the way Oracle works. At least you can use DUAL, i.e. `select to_date('01011912', 'DDMMYYYY') from dual`.

Comment: In PL/SQL, you can do an assignment.

Comment: What is your client interface? How are you providing the string and how do you want to get the output back? You can use either SQL or PL/SQL. Which is best depends on what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SQL then to use a query you need to use a `SELECT` statement:

```sql
SELECT TO_DATE('01011912', 'DDMMYYYY') FROM DUAL
```

From Oracle 23, you can omit `FROM DUAL` and just use:

```sql
SELECT TO_DATE('01011912', 'DDMMYYYY')
```

But you still **MUST** use the `SELECT` keyword (as that is just how the SQL syntax works, in all SQL dialects not just Oracle).

---

If are using PL/SQL (Oracle's procedural language extension) then you can use:

```sql
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TO_DATE('01011912', 'DDMMYYYY'));
END;
/
```

Which does not require either `SELECT` or `FROM` but does require `BEGIN` and `END` to start and end the PL/SQL block.